# INSERT INTO database won't work

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to enter data into a database (it's a reactions script) but I always get a error and it's driving my crazy.

This is the code that i'm using:

```
    if (mysql_query("INSERT INTO gastenboek (naam, bericht, datum, ip, plantid) VALUES ('".trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['naam']))."', '".trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bericht']))."', $datum_reactie, '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])."', $id)")) {
        echo '<span style="color:green; font-weight: bold"Je reactie is succesvol toegevoegd!</span>';
    } else {
        echo '<span style="color:green; font-weight: bold">Er is iets fout gegaan en je reactie is niet toegevoegd. Probeer het later opnieuw.</span>';
    }
```

That doesn't seem to work.
But when I display the data using the following code:

```
    if (mysql_query("INSERT INTO gastenboek (naam, bericht, datum, ip, plantid) VALUES ('".trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['naam']))."', '".trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bericht']))."', $datum_reactie, '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])."', $id)")) {
        echo '<span style="color:green; font-weight: bold"Je reactie is succesvol toegevoegd!</span>';
    } else {
        echo '<span style="color:green; font-weight: bold">Er is iets fout gegaan en je reactie is niet toegevoegd. Probeer het later opnieuw.</span>';
        $qry = "INSERT INTO gastenboek (naam, bericht, datum, ip, plantid) VALUES ('".trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['naam']))."', '".trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bericht']))."', $datum_reactie, '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])."', $id)"; echo $qry;
    }
```

This is what I get:
[image]

So everything seems right?

This is what my database looks like:
[image]

Comment: `So everything seems right?` no, you need single quotes around date

Comment: use bind variables; would have prevented this error & protected you against sql injection attacks

Comment: you cold add some basic error checking, i dont know how you expect to debug code if you dont even check for errors

Comment: You'd be better using a date datatype for your date column, but it needs quotes

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need quotes around the date value in the third column.

You might want to use bind variables because it will make the quotes easier to work with and safer (from a SQL injection perspective).  Something like this:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, "INSERT INTO gastenboek (name, bericht, datum, ip, platid) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

mysqli_stmt_bind_param ($stmt, 'sssss', $_POST['naam'], $_POST['bericht'], $datum_reactie, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $id);

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to quote your 'date' field. This might fix things for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php):

```
echo mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link) . "\n";
```

That returns the last error of mysql. As said Lashane put '$datum_reactie'

Also, I have to say it: "don't use msysql_*, it's deprecated".

Answer (score 0):

A query could fail due to a variety of reasons - syntax error, non-existing table/columns, insufficient permissions, etc. Your best bet would be to print error on failure (in else{}) using mysql_error()/mysql_errno().

Answer (score 0):

Yep...as all are varchar or text you have to have all values single quoted